Only getting back 100 contacts, even though I am not setting a page number
The following code only returns 100 contacts. Looking at the documentation it says, that this will occur when setting a page number value.. but I am not ... I just want to get back all the contacts in the system.
var result = await Api.GetContactsAsync(accessToken: XeroToken.AccessToken, xeroTenantId: TenantId, summaryOnly: true, searchTerm: searchPhrase);

Search phrase is null.. there are 100's more but I can't figure out how to get them all out in one call...

You should use pagination. https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/requests-and-responses#retrieving-paged-resources

APIs rarely return everything just because you don't specify a quantity. According to the documentation linked above, the default is 100, and the maximum is 1000. So you will need pagination unless you have <1000 records (and even then, building it in a future-proof way is sensible)

From the Xero documentation - https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/accounting/invoices
when "summaryOnly" parameter is used, pagination is enforced by default.
